# How to add python dictionary as a command line argument when running other file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ubuntu

I'm running a python file from another python file using `subprocess.call()` method.

```
import job_parser

job_info=dict()

job_info['key1']='v1'

job_info['key2']='v2'

job_command="python job_parser.py --job {0}"

subprocess.call(job_command.format(job_info).split())
```

here I want place this `job_info` dictionary into the `job_command`. later I will parse this argument in `job_parser.py` and use it as dictionary.
I tried doing `json.dumps()` and converting to a raw string , these methods are not working.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `subprocess.call(['python', 'job_parser.py', '--job', json.dumps(job_info)])`

Comment: On the first place, why not make an importable module out of `job_parser.py`?

Comment: @bereal added import statement.

Comment: @OferSadan in my requirement i can't use import and using it, there are some other dependencies I have with this process in my project.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for your suggestion, I tried the way you mentioned, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess module is for calling external command like you want to run a os command or any external file you can use subprocess module.

If you want call a python script from another python script, you can import and python module and call the required function from imported python module.

in your case you can define a function call `entry_point` which is like entry point for the task you want to do in `job_parser.py`.

`job_parser.py`

```
def entry_point(input_dict):
    # do_your_stuff
```

then you call this function like this in you script

```
import job_parser

job_info=dict()

job_info['key1']='v1'

job_info['key2']='v2'

job_parser.entry_point(job_info)
```

Comment: in my requirement i can't use import and use it. so i have to use this subprocess.call() method only.